# MySQL выборка из БД

Tags: mysql

Таблица `books` (`id`, `name`)

Таблица `authors` (`id`, `name`)

Таблица `authors-books` (`author_id`, `book_id`)

Как выбрать все книги и присоединить к каждой книге её авторов?

```
SELECT a.name as book,
       c.name as authors
FROM books a
    INNER JOIN authors_books b
        ON a.id = b.book_id
    INNER JOIN authors c
        ON b.author_id = c.id
```

Не могу понять, где ошибка в запросе.

Comment: ошибок не видно. вопрос лишь в том, в каком именно виде нужны выходные данные. Такой запрос вернет много строк на одну книгу, по одному автору в строке. обычно этого достаточно и разбор и правильный вывод осуществляется на клиенте. Если же вы хотите скажем получить по одной записи на книгу, то надо решить в каком виде при этом должны быть авторы и после этого воспользоваться group by и group_concat, например

Comment: в чём ошибка-то выражается?